# How does $scope get initialised?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I haven't been working with AngularJs for very long and have run into a problem that I fixed but want to know if I'm doing the right thing?

I created a view with a ng-model like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
    <select ng-model="user.UserTypeId" ng-options="item.UserType for item in userTypes" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Now I thought I could set the initial value of $scope.user.UserTypeId like so:

```
$scope.userTypes = [
    { UserTypeId: "FB1AE6EA-D94F-4EC9-8FE8-44178D45D9C9", UserType: "Admin" },
    { UserTypeId: "FF6DE9DB-195D-48F8-87AB-E56B49E3A9D8", UserType: "User" }
];

$scope.user.UserTypeId = $scope.userTypes[0];
```

But on the execute of the controller I get a "undefined" on the $scope.user object. I have fixed this by initializing $scope.user at the top of the controller.

```
$scope.user = {};
```

My question is am I doing this the right way? I would think that angularJs would of done this for me and I wouldn't have to initialize every object I have in my ng-model or is this the way it is done?

Comment: AngularJS will only do it if you interact with the input and change the value. At that time it would create the property and assign value.

Comment: `ng-model` will create object if it doesn't exist but controller script has to be run before the html can be compiled so you can't add a property to non-existant object before it is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular, really. It is just JavaScript running into an error. You're trying to add an attribute (UserType) to an object that doesn't yet exist ($scope.user).

Creating an empty object as you do is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it the right way. You need to initialize the parent property of nested properties - this is how JavaScript works. However, if you had set ng-model="userTypeId" (non-nested) then you wouldn't need to initialize $scope.userTypeId in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The controller extends a new scope, this is what I understood. When, your controller gets instantiated, a new scope is created, hence your directives in this new scope will be created later.